# Test Train Split in python

Tags: training-data

What does `test_size`,`random_state` and `stratify` mean in train-test splitting in python?

My codes are below :

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,test_size = 0.25, random_state =0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)



from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,stratify=Y, random_state=42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

`test_size : float, int, None, optional`

> If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion
>   of the dataset to include in the test split. If int, represents the
>   absolute number of test samples. If None, the value is set to the
>   complement of the train size. By default, the value is set to 0.25.
>   The default will change in version 0.21. It will remain 0.25 only if
>   train_size is unspecified, otherwise it will complement the specified
>   train_size.

`train_size : float, int, or None, default None`

> If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion
>   of the dataset to include in the train split. If int, represents the
>   absolute number of train samples. If None, the value is automatically
>   set to the complement of the test size.

`random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)`

> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;
>   If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;
>   If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used
>   by np.random.

You can find all these explanations in the documentation at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html